# Trying to remove the radius of this SVG Icon - any ideas how?

Tags: html, css, svg

Does anyone know why this social icon in SVG format has slight curved radius border? I'd like a square icon. How do I edit this to be a square? Using CSS or just edit the actual code in the SVG? Thanks

```
<svg height="512" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><rect height="512" rx="64" ry="64" width="512" fill="#0083be"/><g fill="#fff"><path d="M61.05316483 178.66808913h85.76013915v257.9625333H61.05316483zM104.5127998 54.28063176c-29.34185723 0-48.512575 19.29035996-48.512575 44.5737057 0 24.75194797 18.5880448 44.57370568 47.37675114 44.57370568h.55470467c29.9027771 0 48.5156826-19.8217577 48.5156826-44.5737057-.55470467-25.28334572-18.6113517-44.57370568-47.9345634-44.57370568zM357.27944394 172.60209055c-45.4904445 0-65.8669069 25.01764686-77.27642064 42.58951v-36.52349588h-85.73838603c1.13737765 24.1972433 0 257.9625333 0 257.9625333h85.73683224V292.56591023c0-7.7114826.55470468-15.4198576 2.82790618-20.93116706 6.1872101-15.39965828 20.30498783-31.35246744 43.9925865-31.35246744 31.01218643 0 43.43632805 23.66429176 43.43632805 58.3278955v138.02046672h85.74149362v-147.9305687c0-79.2373094-42.30516557-116.0979787-98.7203399-116.0979787z"/></g></svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `rx` and `ry` parameters from `rect` tag.

```html
<svg height="512" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><rect height="512" width="512" fill="#0083be"/><g fill="#fff"><path d="M61.05316483 178.66808913h85.76013915v257.9625333H61.05316483zM104.5127998 54.28063176c-29.34185723 0-48.512575 19.29035996-48.512575 44.5737057 0 24.75194797 18.5880448 44.57370568 47.37675114 44.57370568h.55470467c29.9027771 0 48.5156826-19.8217577 48.5156826-44.5737057-.55470467-25.28334572-18.6113517-44.57370568-47.9345634-44.57370568zM357.27944394 172.60209055c-45.4904445 0-65.8669069 25.01764686-77.27642064 42.58951v-36.52349588h-85.73838603c1.13737765 24.1972433 0 257.9625333 0 257.9625333h85.73683224V292.56591023c0-7.7114826.55470468-15.4198576 2.82790618-20.93116706 6.1872101-15.39965828 20.30498783-31.35246744 43.9925865-31.35246744 31.01218643 0 43.43632805 23.66429176 43.43632805 58.3278955v138.02046672h85.74149362v-147.9305687c0-79.2373094-42.30516557-116.0979787-98.7203399-116.0979787z"/></g></svg>
```